# Why does C have separate name spaces for tags and identifiers?

Tags: c, namespaces

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/name_space):

> 1) Label name space: all identifiers declared as labels.
>
> 2) **Tag names**: all identifiers declared as names of structs, unions and enumerated types.
>
> 3) Member names: all identifiers declared as members of any one struct or union. Every struct and union introduces its own name space of this kind.
>
> 4) **All other identifiers**, called ordinary identifiers to distinguish from (1-3) (function names, object names, typedef names, enumeration constants).

This allows for code like this (among other things):

```
struct Point { int x, y; };
struct Point Point;
```

This code seems somewhat unclear to me as Point can refer to both a type and an instance of a struct. What was the motivation behind having separate name spaces for tags and other identifiers?

Comment: To have something like `struct Point Point;` possible?

Comment: Why would you want to write code like that? Is it not confusing to have the same identifier refer to both a struct type and a struct instance?

Comment: Style considerations are separate from the syntax considerations. The fact is that such a constructs are unambiguous and providing more flexibility.

Comment: Something like `typedef struct Point Point;` is rather common.

Comment: No, @BenBurk, it is not particularly confusing, because tag names always are disambiguated from regular identifiers by the appearance of the appropriate keyword: *`struct`* `Point` and *`enum`* `color` and *`union`* `stuff`.  Furthermore, tags are used only in type names, so they are disambiguated by context.  And in a scope in which there is only one object of interest of a given type, it does not seem unnatural to me to use an identifier for that object that is directly associated with its type's name.

Comment: In your example, there's no conflict or ambiguity. `struct Point` is the type, and `Point` is the instance of the struct.

Comment: Member names used to be global and would therefore conflict with struct/union/enum tags if those weren't in their own namespace. Perhaps that has something to do with it. It is weird, though and the fact that structs/unions/enums share the same tag namespace makes it even weirder (I heard some pre-ANSI compilers had separate tag namespaces for those 3, but that wasn't standardized).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual question posed is

> What was the motivation behind having separate name spaces for tags and other identifiers?

This can be answered only by reference to the standard committee's rationale document, which in fact does address the matter, however briefly:

> Pre-C89 implementations varied considerably in the number of separate name spaces maintained. The position adopted in the Standard is to permit as many separate name spaces as can be distinguished by context, except that all tags (struct, union, and enum) comprise a single name space.

([C99 rationale](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) document,<sup>*</sup> section 6.2.3)

Thus, it is explicitly intentional that code such as

```
struct point { int point; } point = { .point = 0 };
goto point;
point:
return point.point;
```

is permitted.  My interpretation of the rationale is that the intention was to be unrestrictive, though it remains unclear why the different kinds of tags were not given separate namespaces.  This could not have been accidental, so one or more parties represented on the committee must have opposed separate tag namespaces, and they managed to prevail.  Such opposition could very well have been for business instead of technical reasons.

---

<sup>*</sup>As far as I am aware, there is no rationale document for the C2011 standard. At least, not yet.

Comment: Given the quote it sounds like the committee was trying to maintain compatibility for as much existing code as possible. If code in the wild depended on compilers maintaining separate namespaces well ...

Comment: @SoronelHaetir, I don't follow that analysis.  Existing code that did not assume separate name spaces for different tag types would still have worked with multiple tag namespaces, but code that did assume separate namespaces does not work with just one.  What you gain by limiting it to one tag namespace is conformance for *compilers* that did it that way already.  And the committee has always had representation from multiple compiler makers.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Having separate namespaces was a matter of compatibility with existing code. Not having even more separate namespaces for different types of tags was a matter of not imposing new requirements on an existing implementation whose owner carried sufficient weight in the committee. :-)

Comment: @JohnBollinger: indeed, the choice made to have a single namespace for `struct`, `union` and `enum` tags broke existing practice as early compilers used a different namespace for `struct` and `union` tags (for example Whitesmith C, 1982). They probably thought having 3 different namespaces for `struct` `union` and `enum` was useless and  confusing and it was less of problem for some software to need patching than for many compilers to need updating. Very early Unix C compilers used a single namespace for struct members, which explains why the `struct tm` members are prefixed with `tm_`

Comment: Dennis M. Ritchie's original *C Reference Manual* from 1974 ( https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/cman.pdf ) had this language regarding `struct` tags and members: *The names of structure members and structure tags may be the same as ordinary variables, since a distinction can be made by context. However, names of tags and members must be distinct. The same member name can appear in different structures only if the two members are of the same type and if their origin with respect to their structure is the same; thus separate structures can share a common initial segment.*